# Relationship between the sum of the digits of an integer in different bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ be two bases in which $n$ can be represented. Then:

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i a^i = \sum_{j=0}^l \beta_j b^j$$.

I am specifically interested in the quantities $S_a = \sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i$ and $S_b = \sum_{j=0}^l \beta_j$.  In particular, if I know $a$, $b$, and one of $S_a$ or $S_b$, can I determine the other sum without having to know $n$?  if so, how?

Comment: @player3236 How did you manage to construct that?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Take $a=10, b=2, S_b=1$, then $n$ can be any power of 2.

Comment: I think the only way you can know this is if $b$ is a power of $a$ and $S_b=1.$  In that case you know $S_a=1$

Comment: @player3236 yes, that's true.  I think that would be a solid counter-example for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bases are *prime numbers*, and if the representations are *standard*—that is, $\alpha_i\in\{0,1,\ldots,a-1\}$ and $\beta_j\in\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}$, then Legendre’s formula for evaluating the the greatest power $v_p(n!)$ of a prime $p$, dividing $n!$ is given by
$$v_p(n!)=\frac{n-S_p}{p-1}\,.$$
This immediately leads to the identity
$$S_a+(a-1)v_a(n!)=S_b+(b-1)v_b(n!)\,.$$
This seems to demand that knowledge of $n$ is necessary to obtain say $S_b$ if you only knew $a,b$ and $S_a$.